# How to receive ephemeral messages though a selfbot?

Tags: python, websocket, discord

Im currently developing an API for Midjourney and im using a websocket that connects to the discord gateway. The weird thing is that it doesn’t receive ephemeral messages. My intent integer is `3276797`.

Expectation:
Should receive those messages.

Reality:
It doesn’t.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How can i receive these ephemeral messages? I currently am unable to get them through the gataway.